# Azure blob storage, how to implement version of any document or files

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, paas

In Azure blob storage, I would like to store multiple version of same file( file name), I mean how to implement versioning in Azure blob storage.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe your problem in more details.

Answer (score 4):

Azure Blob Versioning is Generally Available now.
From azure portal Under Data Protection >> Tracking >> Turn on Versioning option is available.
This will completely solve your problem. A complete guide with C# code sample is available in the link below on document versioning in Azure Blob Storage.
https://subhankarsarkar.com/document-versioning-with-azure-blob-storage/

Code Sample for downloading a file by version

```
public async Task<byte[]> DownloadBlobAsync(string fileToDownload, string fileVersion)
{
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    var blobClient = BlobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(fileToDownload);
    // WithVersion() is the key piece here
    var blob = blobClient.WithVersion(fileVersion);
    await blob.DownloadToAsync(ms);
    return ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Restore a file to a specific version

```
public void RestoreFileToSpecificVersion(string storageAccountName, string containerName, string fileName, string sourceVersion)
{
    var blobClient = BlobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(fileName); // this is pointing to the current version
    //versionid={} is the most important piece here
    var sourceBlobUri = new Uri(
    string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}/{2}?versionid={3}",
    storageAccountName, containerName, fileName, sourceVersion));

    // Since it will copy in the same storage account's container, it's a synchronous process
    // Copy Operation will make the specic version as current version
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob-from-url#request-headers
    blobClient.StartCopyFromUri(sourceBlobUri);
}
```

Delete a file by it's version

```
public async Task DeleteSpecificVersion(string fileName, string versionToDelete)
{
   var blobClient = BlobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(fileName).WithVersion(versionToDelete);
   await blobClient.DeleteAsync();
}
```

Comment: Please insert some code from URL you posted. Remember that link can become unavailable in the future.

Comment: @subhankars - read your blog on Document versioning for Blob Storage, great explanation!
But I have a question, what if I want to fetch the most recent Version ID of a blob (only the Blob Version ID, not the actual blob content) ? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @YashGupta I'm glad that you liked my blog. Try this code snippet to find the latest VersionId of the blob in the container. Where fileName is the name of the blob.  `public string GetLatestVersion(string fileName)
        {
            var blobClient = BlobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(fileName);
            var docProperties = blobClient.GetProperties();
            return docProperties.Value.VersionId;
        }`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot @shubhankars

Answer (score 2):

Versioning in Azure Blob Storage is supported through `Snapshot Blob` feature where when you create a snapshot of the blob, a read only copy of the blob is created.

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-blob.